# Conectar a SQL Server a través de pyodbc en Linux

Tags: python, linux, pyodbc

Estoy tratando de conectarme desde un script de Python con la librería pyodbc a un servidor SQL local.
Cuando lo ejecuto desde Windows me puedo conectar sin problemas, pero cuando lo ejecuto desde Linux la conexión se va por timeout.

La conexión desde Windows:

```
def connDB():
    result = False
    try:
        conn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=COMPU-*******\SQLEXPRESS;DATABASE=automatizaciones;Trusted_Connection=yes')
        conn.setdecoding(pyodbc.SQL_CHAR, encoding='utf-8')
        result = True
    except Exception as exception:
        print("Error al conectarse a la base de dato: " + str(exception))
        result = False
    finally:    
        if(result):
            print("NOS CONECTAMOS")
        else:
            print("No se pudo establecer conexión con el servidor")

connDB()
```

La conexión desde Linux:

```
import pyodbc

def connDB():
    result = False
    try:
        conn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server};SERVER=COMPU-*****\SQLEXPRESS;DATABASE=automatizaciones;UID=****;PWD=****')
        conn.setdecoding(pyodbc.SQL_CHAR, encoding='utf-8')
        result = True
    except Exception as exception:
        print("Error al conectarse a la base de dato: " + str(exception))
        result = False
    finally:    
        if(result):
            print("NOS CONECTAMOS")
        else:
            print("No se pudo establecer conexión con el servidor")  

connDB()
```

Agradezco cualquier ayuda.

Comment: No uses el nombre del servidor para conectarte desde linux. Estás asumiendo que puedes resolver WINS en un servidor Linux y pues... siempre será una pésima idea. Usa la IP siempre, sin importar el origen; así podrás depender menos de controladores de dominio y esas cosas...

Comment: Nunca usar la IP, siempre usar los nombres. Esto se resuelve instalando algunos paquetes extra: https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-enable-linux-machines-to-resolve-windows-hostnames/

Comment: Siempre había ido por el camino contrario, @CandidMoe; resolver esos hostnames históricamente ha sido el infierno. Supongo que siempre se aprende algo nuevo. Me queda la duda de esto qué expone y qué hay que asegurar si uno instala estas librerías (uno acá pensando en vulnerabilidades). Pero está cool la solución

Comment: si es local usa una IP, si es externa con dominio .com o parecido debiese ser el dominio ejemplo misitio.com

Comment: Probé utilizando tanto el IP como el nombre del servidor. Pero igualmente sigue dandome timeout a la hora de conectarme. Si, el servidor es local.